# ContextFreeGrammar ambiguity

Tags: context-free-grammar, ambiguous-grammar

given a CFG:   `S--> aS | Sa | b`   I can not find any string that can be made from two different pars trees.

the middle state has left recursion but without eliminating that is there any string that shows the CFG ambiguity ? can anyone help plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply rules 1, 2 and 3, you get:

```
S -> aS -> aSa -> aba
```

And if you apply rules 2, 3 and 1, you get the same string:

```
S -> Sa -> aSa -> aba
```

There's the ambiguity.

Found a tool that checks ambiguity: http://services.brics.dk/java/grammar/demo.html

Enter the grammar and check `analyze the grammar for potential ambiguity`:

```
S : "a" S
  | S "a"
  | "b"
```

Results:

```
*** vertical ambiguity: S[#1] <--> S[#2]
    ambiguous string: "aba"
the grammar is ambiguous!
```

Comment: :) I was just thinking of 'b' to be at the end or begging of String, thanks